# display data from two tables using inner join in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i am using cakephp. i have two tables names and gender. i want display names with gender. but names are displaying with male only. there is female also in gender but that is not selected. my code is below.

```
$this->loadModel("names");

          $modelmerge = $this->names->bindModel(array
    (
        'belongsTo' => array
        (
            'genders' => array
            (
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array
                (
                    'genders.id = names.genders_id'
                )
            )
        )
    ));

    $this->set("names", $this->names->find('all', array('limit' => 10)));
```

this select only where names.genders_id = 1 rest of not selected. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are either on a very old version of CakePHP or you are using really bad naming conventions.

```
$modelmerge = $this->names->bindModel(
  array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
       'genders' => array(
          'classname' => 'Genders',
          'foreignKey' => genders_id
       )
    )
  )
);
$names = $this->names->find('all', array(
  'limit' => 10,
  'recursive' => 0
));
$this->set("names", $names);
```

The following would probably work. However, I suggest you read up on [naming Models/DB columns](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions), [Model Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) and the [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). The links are for version 2.x but I think you might be on 1.3 or earlier so refer to the old book.

Answer (score 0):

you can do without bindModel I think, like

```
$this->names->find('all', 
    array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'joins' =>
            array(
                array(
                    'table'         => 'genders',
                    'type'          => 'INNER',
                    'conditions'    => array('genders.id = names.genders_id')
                ),
            ),
    )
);
```